# angular ui-router ui-view inside ui-view issue

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

index.html

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

test.html is loaded on index.html's ui-view

and inside of test.html

```
<div ui-view="content"></div>
```

and tried to load another html files but it's not working

here is my ui-router

```
.state("index", {
        url: "",
        templateUrl: "views/index.html",
        controller : 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs : 'main'
      })
      .state("test", {
        url: "/test",
        templateUrl: "views/test.html",
        controller : 'testCtrl',
        controllerAs : 'test'
      })
      .state("test.another", {
        url : "another/",
        views:{
          'content':{
            templateUrl :'views/another.html'
          }
        }
      })
```

so basically what I expect is

```
<div ui-view>
  <!-- test.html -->
  <div ui-view="test">
    <!-- another.html -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove `views/test.html` from `test.another`. It should only be for views. So the first one is not required. Also, what's with `another@post`? AFAIK you don't have that label on any of your `ui-view`s.

Comment: Don't change all the code and delete all your comments. Otherwise nobody will know what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

```
  .state("test.another", {
    templateUrl: "views/test.html",
    views:{
      'another@post':{
        templateUrl :'views/another.html'
      }
    }
  })
```

That first templateUrl isn't required; it's only for views, not states.

Also:

```
'another@post':{
```

This means you're targeting a view 'another' in 'post.html'. You neither have a view named 'another', nor a template 'post.html'.

Comment: URL's are individual. For root you'll use `/`, for test `/test`, and for another you'll use `/another`. Angular uses the URLs to internally map the states. So in the end you'll get `/test/another/#/`.